# An insecure signature with message recovery, Dan Boneh

Tags: hash, signature, attack, permutation, message-recovery

Someone can help me to resolve this questions from the book of Dan Boneh (University of Standford)

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Suggestion: first, make a clear mental picture of how the scheme works, by getting familiar with the notation. For example, the first equation tells that the signature step takes the secret key $sk$ and message fragments $m_0$ and $m_1$ to sign, hashes $m_0$, combines the outcome with $m_1$ using XOR/$\oplus$, then pass that thru the inverse trapdoor permutation $I$ which (using the secret key) yields the signature $\sigma$. The next line describes verification. All the math necessary to solve (a) and (b) boils down to understanding how things work and using that $\oplus$ is a group operation.

Comment: fgrieu j'ai fait un tour sur ton profil et j'ai vu que tu t’étais sur Paris. j'écrirais en français pour faciliter la communication. Merci de ta réponse. J'hesite pour la quesion (a), j'aimerais savoir si pour trouver le message m1, il faut utiliser l'équation H(m0) XOR m1 ?

Comment: Oui, vous utilizer l'équation.

Comment: Je suis pas vraiment sur mais comme je connais m0 je peux ecrire H(m1) XOR m1 XOR H(m1)=m1

Comment: _"comme je connais $m_0$"_ est un bon début mais $m_0$ n'apparait pas dans la suite; un typo peut-être?. Suggestion: détailler ce dont on part dans la variante de vérification de (a), les opérations que l'on fait (j'en vois 3, dont 2 en ordre interchangeable), et justifier que l'on abouti à $m_1$  en invoquant les propriétés de $\oplus$ utilisées (dont une est commune à toutes les lois de groupe, au point que l'on l’omet souvent).

Comment: fgrieu Effectivement je me suis trompé dans le commentaire. Ce que je voulais mettre est H(m0) XOR m1 XOR H(m0)=m1. Ceci me semble déjà plus correct. Pour moi, la propriété de XOR utilisé est l'annulation du H(m0), ce qui donne le résultat m1.